# How to call template file in zf2 AbstractRestfulController

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, restful-architecture

I tried to render template file in Zend Framework 2.5 AbstractRestfulController but something wrong or missing in code. What can I do ?

**Controller code**

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

```
class trial extends AbstractRestfulController{

        public function DetailTalktrackAction(){

            $view = new ViewModel();
            $view->setTemplate('api/trial/specialty_talktrack');
            $view->setTerminal(true);
            $html = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer')->render($view);
            echo $html;
            exit;

        }

}
```

**Module folders**

```
- Api
-- config
-- src
--- Api
---- Controller
----- TrialController.php
-- view
--- api
--- trial
---- specialty_talktrack.phtml
```

**Error**

```
 "class": "Zend\\View\\Exception\\RuntimeException",
 "file": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/crush/phase2/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php",
 "line": 494,
 "message": "Zend\\View\\Renderer\\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template \"api/trial/specialty_talktrack\"; resolver could not resolve to a file"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) `template_map`

Your template files should be defined in your `view_manager` config inside a key `template_map`. You can read more on this [in the documentation for `Zend\View`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration).

```
//...
'view_manager' => array(
     'template_map' => array(
         'api/trial/specialty_talktrack' => ...path to your file...
     )
),
//...
```

From the `Zend\View` docs:

> *The TemplateMapResolver allows you to directly map template names
>     to specific templates. The following map would provide locations
>     for a home page template ("application/index/index"), as well as for
>     the layout ("layout/layout"), error pages ("error/index"), and
>     404 page ("error/404"), resolving them to view scripts.*

```
    'template_map' => array(
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'site/layout'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    ),
```

---

### 2) `template_path_stack`

You can also check [the example from the ZF2 album application tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) where they set a `template_path_stack` which is like a default folder to use for searching for template files. If you want to search by default for views in your view folder you could add this path to your `template_path_stack` as follows:

```
'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'Api' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
```

From the `Zend\View` docs:

> *The TemplatePathStack takes an array of directories. Directories
>   are then searched in LIFO order (it's a stack) for the requested
>   view script. This is a nice solution for rapid application
>   development, but potentially introduces performance expense in
>   production due to the number of static calls necessary.*
>
> *The following adds an entry pointing to the view directory
>   of the current module. Make sure your keys differ between modules
>   to ensure that they are not overwritten -- or simply omit the key!*

```
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
```

Comment: 'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
        'template_map' => array(
            'api/trial/specialty_talktrack' => '/../view/api/trial/specialty_talktrack.phtml',
        )
    ),

Not working

Comment: What does not working mean? What error do you get? The same?

Comment: @KrupalPatel Paths to the templates are mostly using [the magic `__DIR__` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) as you can also see [here in the example of the ZF2 album application tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html). Are you sure your path is correct?